# Why does the program crash when I rename field DB_NAME or DB_TABLE?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, adapter, rename

Help, please!

```
public class DB {


 private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
  private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
  private static final String DB_TABLE = "mytab";

  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final String COLUMN_IMG = "img";
  public static final String COLUMN_TXT = "txt";

  private static final String DB_CREATE = 
    "create table " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
      COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
      COLUMN_IMG + " integer, " +
      COLUMN_TXT + " text" +
    ");";

  private final Context mCtx;


  private DBHelper mDBHelper;
  private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

  public DB(Context ctx) {
    mCtx = ctx;
  }

  // открыть подключение
  public void open() {
    mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  }

  // закрыть подключение
  public void close() {
    if (mDBHelper!=null) mDBHelper.close();
  }

  // получить все данные из таблицы DB_TABLE
  public Cursor getAllData() {
    return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
  }

  // добавить запись в DB_TABLE
  public void addRec(String txt, int img) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_TXT, txt);
    cv.put(COLUMN_IMG, img);
    mDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
  }



  // класс по созданию и управлению БД
  private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
      super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    // создаем и заполняем БД
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);

      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        cv.put(COLUMN_TXT, "sometext " + i);
        cv.put(COLUMN_IMG, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
  }
}
```

So the mistake comes if I rename field DB_NAME or DB_TABLE when intializing. If I do not touch the names - everything is ok, but I need to change them. Tried to change the emulator - didn't help.

Comment: if you change field you also have to change version

Comment: Post your logcat then.....

Comment: uninstall privious one and install

Comment: PUtting schema creation in Java code seems silly to me.  Create the schema by executing SQL commands and have it ready when the app starts up.

Comment: 09-16 11:57:28.531: W/dalvikvm(447): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-16 11:57:28.591: E/AndroidRuntime(447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 11:57:28.591: E/AndroidRuntime(447): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.patufedor.scbi/ru.patufedor.scbi.User}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Teachers: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Teachers

Comment: @duffymo I know, but where should I create schema? In what part of creating a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to upgrade the version of your database, so increment one on it, and if you want to save the previous informations of your database, implement it inside your onUpgrade:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
     //implement your logic of saving your infos here
}
```

If you don't mind on cleanning up your database, just do like that:

```
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + DATABASE_TABLE+"'");
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Comment: Tried as you've adviced. Printed such mistake:09-16 11:57:28.591: E/AndroidRuntime(447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 11:57:28.591: E/AndroidRuntime(447): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.patufedor.scbi/ru.patufedor.scbi.User}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Teachers: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Teachers

Comment: Did you try running the "onCreate(db)" inside the onUpgrade? It seems the tables were dropped but not created again. Did you upgraded your DB_VERSION variable to 2?

Comment: Yes, of cource I did that (your second suggestion) @Override
     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + DB_TABLE+"'");
         onCreate(db);
     }

Comment: @ Bruno Franco. I don't understand how it works but I chnged version to 3 and it works now. Thank you and sorry for wating your time)

Comment: You are welcome, we are here to help each other. If you can mark this answer as right, i would appreciate.